# multiple values insert join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, insert

I have a query submitting multiple items in table `a`.

For example:

```
insert into a values(id,name) (5,'john'),(6,'smith');
```

Though I also need to select some third value from other table with this id.

For example:

```
insert into a values(id,name,money) (5,'john',(select money from b where id=5)),(6,'smith',(select money from b where id=6));
```

The problem with the above is that it's a bit repetitive and also uses sub selects.

I wonder if it's possible to rewrite this using `JOIN`, (which should also reassure that there *is* a relation to the table b on that given id, lest it inserts a NULL).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're allowed only one `SELECT` for each `INSERT` so you need to re-write this to select multiple rows, not insert multiple values at once. Could you create a temporary table with the two sets of values in it and `INSERT` those with a `JOIN`?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _tmp_a (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO _tmp_a (5, 'john'), (6, 'smith')
INSERT INTO a (id, name, money) SELECT _tmp_a.id, _tmp_a.name, b.money FROM _tmp_a LEFT JOIN b ON b.id=_tmp_a.id
```

Comment: Well why not! This above looks great, I'm going to try it out. I also wonder if it's possible to replace `left join` to `join`, so it wouldn't insert the rows with money equal to `null`. I'll check it out as well :)

Comment: You can use `RIGHT JOIN` if you want to skip those entries without corresponding values on the "right" side.